# Does the box api provide a way to see a user's mentions?

Tags: box-api

In the v2 API, i see the events endpoint and the Comments event type.  But I don't see anyway of retrieving Comments where I've been explicitly mentioned; how do I know, other than parsing the comment content that I've been called out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API currently does not support @mentions (viewing/creating). We'll be building this into the API in the future but are currently working on other things.

Answer (score 0):

We've added the ability to add @comments via the API, though there still isn't anything to easily determine an @comment via /Events.

http://developers.box.com/docs/#comments

curl https://api.box.com/2.0/files/[FILE_ID]/comments
H- Bearer XXXXX
d- {"tagged_message": "Tagged mention for @[USER_ID:USER_NAME]"}
X- POST